# Capturing the focus event from DOMElement.focus()

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0

I have a polymer web component (might not even matter) that contains a bunch of focusable controls (inputs and buttons), I've attached an event listener for the `focus` event on it.

Using the keyboard, I am able to tab thru the controls, but when I'm writing the unit tests, I call `DOMElement.focus()`, but the event listener callback isn't firing.  Which makes me think that when you focus programatically, the focus event doesn't fire at all.

Am I mistaken?  Is there a way to detect the `focus` event using `DOMElement.focus()`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Bind the boolean value of the attribute focused to `isFocus`.
2. Add an Observer for `isFocus`, call the function `inputIsFocus`.
3. if isFocus === true { // do something} else { // do something else}

paper-button

```
<paper-button focused={{isFocus}}>I am Focus</paper-button>
```

paper-input

```
<paper-button focused={{isFocus}}>I am Focus</paper-button>
```

Handler

```
Polymer({

  is: 'x-custom',

  properties: {
    isFocus: {
      type: Boolean,
      value: false
    }
  },
observers: [
  'userIsFocus(isFocus)'
],
inputIsFocus: function: (){
if isFocus === true {
 // do someting}
else {
 // do someting else
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joel.  However, the question was more targeted towards unit testing.  My component works perfectly fine.  It's just when I'm running unit tests and focusing on the component using .focus() that fails to trigger the callback event.